# I do not want my VBA code to change sheets

Tags: excel, vba, screen, spreadsheet

So, I'm trying to use the code to simply refresh a Pivot Table every time an alteration is made in the main sheet (dashboard).

As I need to keep it clean, I have another sheet, where all infos are, named `historic_var`.

The problem is, when I run the code, it works well, but it changes to the sheet that has no use (unless keep the infos safe). What can I do? Already tried `application.ScreenUpdating = False`

The current code is:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <= 14 Then
        Sheets("historic_var").Select
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1").PivotCache.Refresh
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("historic_var").PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1").PivotCache.Refresh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can update the table without changing the sheet. Try this out...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column <= 14 Then
    
    Sheets("historic_var").PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1").PivotCache.Refresh
    End If

End Sub
```